# PHP MySQL Adding fifth column to query breaks script

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I'm trying to add user groups to my login system, however whenever I add the final column into the script it breaks everything. I am trying to add it to my prepare statement and bind it to a variable, and then store the value into a $_SESSION variable. I can't tell where I am going wrong with this.

Here's my code before I add the last column:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli)
{
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email=? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $password= hash('key', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1)
    {
        if(checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true)
        {
            //account is locked
            //send email to user saying acc is locked
            return false;
        } 
        else
        {
            if($db_password == $password)
            {
                //password is correct
                //get useragent string of the user
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                //XSS protect as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                //XSS protect as we might print this value.
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('key', $password . $user_browser);
                //login successful
                return true;
            } 
            else
            {
                //password is not correct
                //we record this attempt in the db
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id, '$now')");

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And here is after:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli)
{
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, group FROM members WHERE email=? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $usr_group);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $password= hash('key', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1)
    {
        if(checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true)
        {
            //account is locked
            //send email to user saying acc is locked
            return false;
        } 
        else
        {
            if($db_password == $password)
            {
                //password is correct
                //get useragent string of the user
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                //XSS protect as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                //XSS protect as we might print this value.
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['user_group'] = $usr_group;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('key', $password . $user_browser);
                //login successful
                return true;
            } 
            else
            {
                //password is not correct
                //we record this attempt in the db
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id, '$now')");

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, try wrap it around with backticks **`** (or avoid using that term in your table schema):

```
"SELECT id, username, password, salt, `group` FROM members WHERE email=? LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: I was not aware group was a reserved word, I have changed the column name to "usrgroup" and altered all the respective code, thank you for your help, I will set this to answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using group, since that is a reserved word in SQL.

Change your statement to become:
SELECT id, username, password, salt, usergroup FROM members WHERE email=? LIMIT 1

That means that you need to rename your column:
ALTER TABLE members RENAME COLUMN group to usergroup;